# Close popup on form submit and display success/error message on parent component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, modalpopup

I am opening a form to add a user in a popup using the toggle method. I want to close the toggle on success and display a message in my parent component.

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````
This is my toggle method
`````````````````````````````  
 toggle = () => {
  this.setState({
  modal: !this.state.modal
 });
 }

  <Modals title={'Add User'} isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle= 
   {this.toggle} />

   This is the method written in modal popup
   addApi = (data) => {
    axios.post(`http://***************/api/adduser`,data) //api call
    .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      successMsg : 'Record Added Successfully'
    })
    this.props.toggle(); // to close pop up. Is it right?
  })

   In my parent component:
  let {successMsg}=this.state;
     {successMsg ? successMsg : ''}

 ````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````

How do I close the pop-up the correct way and display a success message in the parent component?

Comment: I think that should work. Is it working ?

Comment: No, it is not working. My popup is losing but i am not getting successMsg. I am getting it as blank. How do I refresh the parent after popup is closed and get success message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, actually what you want is success message to be passed to your parent component with modal closed.You can do something like this

```
addApi = (data) => {
        axios.post(`http://***************/api/adduser`,data) //api call
        .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          successMsg : 'Record Added Successfully'
        })
        this.props.toggle({
          successMsg : 'Record Added Successfully'
        }); // to close pop up. Is it right?
    //now your parent component will get successMsg in an object, you can use it whereever you want

      })
```

In your parent component , you can add something like this:

```
toggle = (data) => {
  this.setState({
  modal: !this.state.modal,
  successMsg: data.successMsg
 });
 }
```

Is it what you wanted ?

Comment: Yes, also I wanted to confirm if this was the correct method to close the toggle after submit.

Comment: Hi, My parent component is not refreshing after successful add, edit. How to do it?